# Where does API Gateway direct when more than one pattern matches?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Unlike CloudFront, there's no "Precedence" list in the API Gateway.

If two or more path patterns match a given url in an API, which one gets selected?

Example:

```
/
GET
  /{a}
  GET
  /static
  GET
```

When I then go to gibberish.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/stage/static, will the {a} pattern trigger? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Does API Gateway allow you to provision ambiguous patterns?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes, I have attempted it and subsequently deployed the API. It *seems* to favor the static url when possible, but since it does not appear documented, I am wary.

Comment: I haven't been able to dig it up from the docs, either. 
 Arguably, though, that isn't ambiguous.  `GET /{foo}` and `GET /{bar}` would be ambiguous, since what's inside the braces is the name of a parameter and the braces imply accepting any value, and they can't both match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API Gateway will not let you create ambiguous paths like

/{foo}
/{bar}

However, given two paths that match, like in your example, API Gateway will choose the one that has more static value matches.

### Your Example

/{a}
/static

You hit **/static**, API Gateway will chose **/static.**

### Another Example:

/{foo}/static/{bar}
/value/static/{bar}

If you hit **/value/static/baz**, API Gateway will choose **/value/static/{bar}**